# Laplace Transform of this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I'm trying to find the Laplace transform of this:

$f(t) = e^{-2t}$

my assumption was

$
\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt
$

but for some reason when I try integrating with parts I end up with $\frac{1}{s-1}$ which isn't right... any guide on how to break this down would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2t}e^{-st}\,dt$$
Substitute $u=e^t \implies du=udt$
$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{-2}u^{-s}\,\dfrac {du}{u}$$
$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{-(3+s)}\,{du}$$
$$I=\dfrac {u^{-(s+2)}}{-(s+2)}\Big|_1^{\infty}$$
$$\implies I(s)=\dfrac 1 {s+2}$$

Comment: Maybe I an nitpicking, but how do you justify the substitution in divergent improper integral (the convergent case is OK)? I mean, for $s>-2$ the result is correct, but otherwise, doubtful.

Comment: I only consider the case $s >-2$ @Anixx

Comment: I am asking because similar results are usually produced by computer algebra systems and I do not see a justification. For instance, Laplace transform of $\exp x$ is usually returned as $\frac1{x-1}$. Hmmm.

Comment: You're completely right. But I always have seen in Laplace transform table the condition on the prameter $s$ @Anixx

Answer (score 5):

By the substitution $u=(2+s)t$ we get $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(2+s)t}dt=\frac1 {2+s} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}du=\frac1 {2+s} $

Answer (score 4):

There is no need of IBP.

$$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt =\int_0^\infty e^{-2t}e^{-st}dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+2)t}dt 
 = \frac{-1}{s+2}[0-1] = \frac{1}{s+2}$$